# Printing list of elements with atributes from xml document using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need quite an odd problem to fix. I need an XSLT stylesheet that will print the list of elements and their attributes for an xml document with unknown structure. After many tries I managed to create such a thing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<HTML>
<title></title>
<body>  

<xsl:call-template name="recurs">
<xsl:with-param name="nextnodes" select="child::*" />
</xsl:call-template>

</body>
</HTML>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="recurs">
<xsl:param name="nextnodes" />
<xsl:for-each select="$nextnodes">
<xsl:if test="not(name(current())=name(following::*)) and  not(name(current())=name(following::*/descendant::*)) ">
    Element <b><xsl:value-of select="name(current())" /></b> has attributes <text> </text>
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
    <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
    <b><xsl:value-of select="name(current())" /><text>.</text></b>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <b><xsl:value-of select="name(current())" /><text>,  </text></b>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <br /><br />
</xsl:if>
<xsl:call-template name="recurs">
    <xsl:with-param name="nextnodes" select="child::*" />
</xsl:call-template>

</xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For such test case, when element book appears once more inside other element, it works fine though:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="task3_4a.xsl"?>
<catalog subnodes="2">

<cities country="England">
<city name="London" region="London" population="10000" />
<city name="New South Wales" region="Wales" population="800000" />

</cities> 

<articles country="USA">
<article name="My lovely country" src="art1.txt" />
<article name="Places to visit" src="art2.txt" />
<article name="Article 3" src="art3.txt" />
</articles>

<books>
<book title="Warhammer">
</book>
<book title="We fought for truth"> 
</book>
</books>

<scientifics  atr = " ">
<book title="Warhammer">
</book> 
</scientifics>
</catalog>
```

But when I try another test, with element article inside books, it fails to manage xml properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="task3_4a.xsl"?>
<catalog subnodes="2">

<cities country="England">
<city name="London" region="London" population="10000" />
<city name="New South Wales" region="Wales" population="800000" />

</cities> 

<articles country="USA">
<article name="My lovely country" src="art1.txt" />
<article name="Places to visit" src="art2.txt" />
<article name="Article 3" src="art3.txt" />
</articles>

<books>
<book title="Warhammer">
<article name="My lovely country" src="art1.txt" /> 
</book>
<book title="We fought for truth"> 
<article name="My lovely country" src="art1.txt" /> 
</book>
</books>

<scientifics  atr = " ">
<book title="Warhammer">

<article name="My lovely country" src="art1.txt" /> 
</book> 

</scientifics>

</catalog>
```

The output now contains string "Element article has attributes name, src." 3 times. And I have no idea how to fix it...

Comment: It traverses down the 3 possible node hierarchies to get to the <article/> nodes. That's why it displays 3 times. You'll need to keep track of the structure found somehow and then later compare to make sure you are not duplicating. 

1. <catalog><article/></catalog>
      
2. <catalog><books><book><article/></book></books></catalog>
        
3. <catalog><scientifics><book><article/></book></scientifics></catalog>

Comment: Do you need each unique element printed out with it's attributes? Or all elements?

Comment: I need all elements from document to be printed with their attributes, but despite that some elements appear more then once in document at different hierarchy levels, there should be only one item in the output list for any such element.

Comment: @ferbolg for that type of operations where you have to accumulate and compare against previous values (just to see if already displayed), XSLT might not be the best solution. XSLT is great for formating and transforming, but for counting and comparing it might be better using a scripting language with  map/dictionary support

Comment: I now realise that some kind of DOM or SAX parsing woulde be better, but the problem is I need an XSLT stylesheet...

Comment: Please, provide the exact wanted output from the transformation.

Comment: What should be done if two `book` elements have differently-named attributes? Should all attributes be listed for one `book` "entry", or should there be more than one `book` entries? Have you thought about this possibility?

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev Sorry, I forgot mention such case. If two book elements have differently-named attributes, we consider them to be different elements and that's why it should be two entries. For my 2d test case I want such output: Element catalog has attributes subnodes. 
Element cities has attributes country.
Element city has attributes name, region, population.
Element articles has attributes country.
Element books has attributes
Element article has attributes name, src.
Element scientifics has attributes atr.
Element book has attributes title.

Comment: @ferbolg: This is much easier to do with XSLT 2.0. Can you use XSLT 2.0 or do you only need an XSLT 1.0 solution?

Answer (score 2):

**I. Here is a very short and simple XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//*"
         group-by="string-join((name(), @*/name()), '|')">
      <xsl:sort select="name()"/>

      <p>
        Element <b><xsl:sequence select="name()"/></b>
        has attributes: <xsl:value-of select="@*/name()" separator=", "/>
      </p>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<catalog subnodes="2">
    <cities country="England">
        <city name="London" region="London" population="10000" />
        <city name="New South Wales" region="Wales" population="800000" />
    </cities>
    <articles country="USA">
        <article name="My lovely country" src="art1.txt" />
        <article name="Places to visit" src="art2.txt" />
        <article name="Article 3" src="art3.txt" />
    </articles>
    <books>
        <book title="Warhammer">
            <article name="My lovely country" src="art1.txt" />
        </book>
        <book title="We fought for truth">
            <article name="My lovely country" src="art1.txt" />
        </book>
    </books>
    <scientifics  atr = " ">
        <book title="Warhammer">
            <article name="My lovely country" src="art1.txt" />
        </book>
    </scientifics>
</catalog>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<p>
        Element <b>article</b>
        has attributes: name, src</p>
<p>
        Element <b>articles</b>
        has attributes: country</p>
<p>
        Element <b>book</b>
        has attributes: title</p>
<p>
        Element <b>books</b>
        has attributes: </p>
<p>
        Element <b>catalog</b>
        has attributes: subnodes</p>
<p>
        Element <b>cities</b>
        has attributes: country</p>
<p>
        Element <b>city</b>
        has attributes: name, region, population</p>
<p>
        Element <b>scientifics</b>
        has attributes: atr</p>
```

**and it is displayed in the browser as**:

Element **article**
        has attributes: name, src

Element **articles**
        has attributes: country

Element **book**
        has attributes: title

Element **books**
        has attributes:

Element **catalog**
        has attributes: subnodes

Element **cities**
        has attributes: country

Element **city**
        has attributes: name, region, population

Element **scientifics**
        has attributes: atr

**II. XSLT 1.0 (two-pass) solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kElByNameandAttrs" match="*"
  use="concat(name(), '|', @_____attribs)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:attribute name="_____attribs">
     <xsl:for-each select="@*">
       <xsl:sort select="name()"/>

       <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ' ')"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:attribute>

   <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2" select=
   "ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)//*
          [generate-id()
          =
           generate-id(key('kElByNameandAttrs',
                           concat(name(),
                                  '|',
                                  @_____attribs)
                           )
                            [1])
           ]"
   >
    <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="pass2">
  <p>
        Element <b><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></b>
        has attributes: <xsl:value-of select="@_____attribs"/></p>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this XSLT 1.0 transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), again the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<p>
        Element <b>article</b>
        has attributes: name src </p>
<p>
        Element <b>articles</b>
        has attributes: country </p>
<p>
        Element <b>book</b>
        has attributes: title </p>
<p>
        Element <b>books</b>
        has attributes: </p>
<p>
        Element <b>catalog</b>
        has attributes: subnodes </p>
<p>
        Element <b>cities</b>
        has attributes: country </p>
<p>
        Element <b>city</b>
        has attributes: name population region </p>
<p>
        Element <b>scientifics</b>
        has attributes: atr </p>
```

Comment: @Dimitri Novatchev Very nice solution +1. Could you please explain this : group-by="string-join((name(), @*/name()), '|')">? As far I understand you group by name and all the attributes? Can this also be done by muenchian grouping in XSLT 1.0?

Comment: @FailedDev: Re: `group-by="string-join((name(), @*/name()), '|')"` . This groups by a string that is the concatenation of the name of the element and the *names* of all its attributes -- all of these are joined by a pipe character. BTW, I added an XSLT 1.0 solution, too. :)

Comment: @Dimitri Novatchev Amazing stuff :) Glad to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

One problem you have is with the use of this XPath

```
<xsl:if test="not(name(current())=name(following::*)) ...
```

Using the axis **following::** will return multiple nodes, but applying the **name()** function will only get the name of the first of the nodes.

So, instead of the following line in your XSLT>...

```
<xsl:if test="not(name(current())=name(following::*)) and  not(name(current())=name(following::*/descendant::*)) ">
```

Try replacing it with the following line instead...

```
<xsl:if test="not(following::*[name() = name(current())])">
```

i.e There is not a following node (in any level of the hierarchy) that doesn't have the same name as the current node.

When you do this, the following will be output:

```
<HTML>
<title></title>
<body>
Element <b>catalog</b> has attributes <text></text><b>subnodes<text>.</text></b><br><br>
Element <b>cities</b> has attributes <text></text><b>country<text>.</text></b><br><br>
Element <b>city</b> has attributes <text></text><b>name<text>,  </text></b><b>region<text>,  </text></b><b>population<text>.</text></b><br><br>
Element <b>articles</b> has attributes <text></text><b>country<text>.</text></b><br><br>
Element <b>books</b> has attributes <text></text><br><br>
Element <b>scientifics</b> has attributes <text></text><b>atr<text>.</text></b><br><br>
Element <b>book</b> has attributes <text></text><b>title<text>.</text></b><br><br>
Element <b>article</b> has attributes <text></text><b>name<text>,  </text></b><b>src<text>.</text></b><br><br></body>
</HTML>
```

Of course, this doesn't solve the problem of matching when two elements with the same name have different attributes, but it should solve your immediate problem of **article** appearing more than once.